# Simulate Repeat/Until in BASIC, and on a single line?

Tags: programming, basic

Is there a way to simulate a Repeat/Until loop in a BASIC language without it, and without using a GOTO statement?

For BASIC languages with command separators, can this be done on a single line without an IF/THEN statement?

Comment: This leads to the question "Why do you want to not use a `GOTO`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html)

Comment: @Mark: It's BASIC, BASIC comes with goto. It doesn't get more readable (which is the point) if you use a complicated construct simulating repeat/until, that's even more "harmful".

Comment: Mr Dijkstra's essay is probably more harmful to CS than the use of the `GOTO` statement; it is quite possible to write structured code in BASIC using `GOTO`, as in early BASICs, when you don't have constructs such as `WHILE...WEND` or `REPEAT...UNTIL`. If you understand how those constructs work at a conceptual level, writing equivalent code using `GOTO` is quite understandable, and doesn't rely on questionable misuse of other constructs, such as the submitted answer (`FOR...NEXT` with `STEP 0`).

Comment: The problem that Mr Dijkstra rightly decried was the _indiscriminate_ use of `GOTO` for branching to more-or-less arbitrary points in the code. It was not unconditionally the use of `GOTO` at any time. However, it has been misread repeatedly, and summarized inaccurately, to the point where it is a cliché, and _that_ is the genesis of my previous comment.

Comment: I contend that Dijkstra's essay has been much less harmful than the `GOTO` statement as it has promoted more-structured approaches to control flow that more clearly communicate programmer intention. The issue isn't merely structure, it's comprehensibility. Any successful computer code will have a long maintenance life so costs accrue not just through lack of structure but also from time taken by each new author in discerning the structure. How quickly can you understand a do/while? What about GOTOs that effect a do/while? What about when the loop body is large and loops are nested?

Comment: There was another application for this years ago, in what was known as 1 or 2 line BASIC challenges. How much code can you possibly fit into a single line and actually write a functional program? Certain commands force the termination of the line and don't allow continuation of normal commands beyond them, such as IF/THEN. And with extreme density code mashed together without line numbers, there is no way to GOTO back to a particular command, somewhere in the middle of a single line of BASIC. The Apple II magazine Nibble had 1 and 2 line programming contests based around this weirdness.

Comment: @Tommy - If the code is complex enough that even with "structured `GOTO`" it is difficult to comprehend and maintain, it needs to be ***thoroughly*** commented - and those comments can be both descriptive and theoretical-code - `130 REM WHILE NOT (QUARK = TOP) -- TOP QUARKS CAUSE FISSION; WE DON'T SEND THEM ON`

Answer (score 3):

What we do is create a FOR/NEXT loop with the special property that we set the STEP rate to zero, so that it will run forever.

To exit the loop, we set the counter equal to the ending value of the FOR loop.

```
10 FOR X = 0 TO 1 STEP 0
20 INPUT "WHAT IS YOUR NAME?"; X$
30 IF LEN(X$) > 0 THEN X = 1
40 NEXT X
```

,

For this to work on a single line, the BASIC needs to support boolean values as a number, so that we can use Boolean Math in place of the IF/THEN statement.

Support for this varies from one BASIC to the next, with some having a True value equal to 1 and others with True equal to -1. The following code checks to see which way this works and compensates for it.

```
10 N = 1 : IF (1 = 1) = -1 THEN N = -1
20 FOR X = 0 TO 1 STEP 0 : INPUT "WHAT IS YOUR NAME?"; X$ : X = (LEN(X$) > 0) * N : NEXT X
```

(Tested in Apple II Microsoft/FP BASIC).

,

EDIT: An even shorter way to do it, that should be compatible across most BASIC languages, as suggested by Jeff Zeitlin:

```
10 N=NOT 0 :FOR X=0 TO 1 STEP 0 :INPUT "WHAT IS YOUR NAME?"; X$ :X=(LEN(X$)>0)*N :NEXT X
```

Comment: As regards variance in the value for TRUE in different BASICs: Why not just say `N = NOT 0`?

Comment: valid, and answering the question. remains the question for the OT: in which way is such an obfuscated construct better, than using the (in BASIC perfectly valid "goto" command), just for NOT using goto ??

Comment: @Tommylee2k - The querent is operating under a misapprehension of what [Mr Dijkstra was saying in his famous (infamous?) essay](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the person asking the question, Dale Mahalko, who appears also to have answered it, doesn't mention Dijkstra at all. Given that he posted both question and answer at almost the same time, one suspects that motivation may have been finding somewhere to put his answer rather than any strong feelings about the literature.

Comment: @Tommy - Indeed; a good catch: I missed that Dale was both querent and respondent. I still think that avoiding `GOTO` in this case is misguided, and that the answer provided relies on a quirky implementation of the `FOR` statement.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin agreed that in the BASIC in use, `GOTO` is definitely the most natural way to implement a repeat/until. A much lower "wait, what?" quotient than `FOR ... STEP 0`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "Querent": is a new word for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @WayneConrad - it's particularly useful in a case like this one, where the querent's query is quite queer.

Comment: I'm usually using

Comment: Cont'd from "I'm usually using ..." ;)

`10 FOR X=0 TO 1:INPUT "WHAT IS YOUR NAME?"; X$ :X=ABS(LEN(X$)>0) :NEXT X`

The ABS function is very common on various dialects and provides a simple mapping for different values of "true" - e.g. Commodore Basic evaluates to -1. Whatever true is, its > 0 and every value >=1 terminates the FOR-NEXT. You don't need the help by an extra variable N and the STEP isn't needed too. Beside this, ABS is much faster in execution time.